# PHP Apache XAMPP Run Multiple Scripts from CLI in Background

Tags: php, command-line-interface, powershell, xampp, background

How can I simultaneously run dozens of PHP scripts in the background from XAMPP's command line interface?

Someone suggested a batch file, but when I tried executing this:

```
start php 1.php
start php 2.php
start php 3.php
```

It only opened a command prompt window; I closed that window, then two more command prompt windows opened up executing 2.php and 3.php.

I want to run as many scripts as I want all simultaneously and all in the background. What is the best way to accomplish this, and how can it be done?

---

**EDIT Here is how to accomplish this:**

1) Download PowerShell 2 (or the compatible version with your Windows version) from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

2) Install it and restart your computer.

3) Make a new file "example.ps1" and save it to a directory of your choice (e.g. c:\examples\example.ps1). Put this code in that file:

```
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\1.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\2.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\3.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\4.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\5.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\6.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\7.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\8.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\9.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\10.php}
start-job {.\c:\xampp\php\php C:\xampp\htdocs\phpfiles\11.php}
```

4) Click on "Start" -> "Run" and type in "powershell" (without quotes).

5) After PowerShell initiates, type in the following and press enter:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then press "y" to set the changes.

6) Now type in (make sure to enter in the full file path):

```
c:\examples\example.ps1
```

7) To see your jobs simply type in:

```
get-job
```

To stop a job use this command:

```
stop-job JobName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some options after your `start`:

```
start /min cmd /c php -f 1.php
...
```

This will suppress the additional command prompts.

Comment: Thanks, but this only minimizes the 3 command prompt windows. Is there a way to run multiple scripts through CLI entirely in the background (in one window only)?

Comment: For that, you will need the POSIX capabilities of PowerShell. Look at this article: http://jtruher.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7143DA6E51A2628D!130.entry

Comment: Thanks! That article is a bit outdated as PowerShell now integrates background jobs. I've updated my question with the full instructions on how to accomplish this.